# Install Single Dependency from package.json with yarn

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I'm having a huge list of dependencies in my `package.json` and at some build step, which is completely independent from others, I only need to resolve a single dependency, but in the version specified in the `package.json`.

Is this even possible? A solution based on `npm` would also be fine.

I thought `yarn add package-name --force` could do it because it will determine the changes, but as there's no node_modules yet, it will also install everything first.

Comment: You could do something like `yarn add "package-name@$(cat ./package.json | jq -r '.devDependencies["package-name"]')"`

Comment: That does the trick indeed. Thank you! :)